# Representing Voxel in different Formats

Tags: graphics, 3d, data-visualization, voxel, volume-rendering

I am new to Graphics. Can someone tell me how do I represent a Voxel with different formats (eg. Rectilinear Grid)

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples on shadertoy using this technique. It's probably the best way to learn, e.g: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdBGRm